# How to join multiple records from a table to a point feature

Tags: arcmap, attribute-joins

I work in ArcMap 10.4.
I have a xls table of 320 records. Some of the records are of the same name (municipality name).
I have a feature point layer of all municipalities in the country. Both the xls table and feature point (.shp) layer have a common ID field - so they are "joinable" and "relatable".
What I need to do is to create a feature point layer for all the 320 records, so they have a spatial attribute too (a point).

So, to illustrate it better:

**ID, Name, POI (.xls)**

1, Town_A, Castle

1, Town_A, Church

1, Town_A, Theatre

2, Town_B, Castle

2, Town_B, Monument

3, Town_C, Castle

...

**ID, Feature point (.shp)**

1, Town_A

2, Town_B

3, Town_C

...

I tried "Join" which didn't work. It kept only one record for one point. "Relate" would work by principle (one-to-many) but I can't export it, it won't append the data.
I hope I making myself clear. I need something which would multiple (copy) the point features by how many records there are in the .xls table. So in the result, there would be many overlapping points (for the cases where they are multiple records for one municipality).

Comment: Hey, can you specify what software are you using?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited it.

Comment: Just to be crystal clear the result of your join you you want 3 stacked points for ID 1 each with a different building types, 2 stacked points for ID 2 and 1 for ID 3?

Comment: It's just an example what I wrote. I want the result to look like in the .xls file, just so that each record will have a spatial geometry point too.

Comment: Compute xy of the points and join it to poi table. This is convertible to points. Yes, as #Hornbyd said you'll have multiple duplicate points.